# Last N Quarter, Month, Week, Date in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want to show Last 2 Quarters, 2 Months, 2 Weeks and 2 days in one chart (As Columns). Dates are in a proddate. Any idea if this is possible. Right now im using separate charts and just putting them side by side.

Comment: what i've done now is create separate charts for quarter, month, week and day, and just put them side by side on the dashboard to make it appear like one chart.

Comment: it would be better if you put this along with the question under the heading **Approach I tried:**.